# How to use intermediate value theorem?

Tags: functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

$f(x)$ can be shown as $1 + x^2$ when $x\le0, x-2$ when $0<x\le2, (x-2)^2$ when $x>2$. Find an interval $\left[a,b\right]$ and a real value $L$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ but there does not exist a real number $c$ which is in the range $(a,b)$ with $f(c) = L$. Why this does not contradict the intermediate value theorem?

I found the discontinuous places of $f(x)$ and I sketched the graph. I want to know a complete explanation for the above question. Please help me

Comment: Where are the discontinuities?  Where does f(x) jump to on either side?  Chose your interval such that it is a relatively small distance on either side of one of the discontinuities (of the domain).  Choose L so that it is smack in the middle of the jump.  Why does the intermediate value theorem not apply?, because the IVT applies to continuous functions.

Comment: There is a discontinuity when x = 0. I don't understand your comment properly. Can you please explain the answer?

Comment: At zero the function jumps for 1 to 0.  Pick a number between those, say... 1/2.  Can you find any interval that doesn't have f (x)=1/2 in it but has f (a) >1/2 and f (b) < 1/2?

Comment: At zero function jumps 1 to -2. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Just do it.  Let a = 0.  f (a)=1.  Let b=2.  f (b)=0.

Comment: Ok I will give a try

Comment: Then I got f(c) = -x/2 + c. What can I do next?

Comment: Please someone give me an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible choice is to let  $a=0$, $b=2$, and $L=\frac12$.

Notice that $f(a) = 1$ and $f(b) = 0$ and hence $L$ is in between $f(a)=1$ and $f(b) = 0$.

Now, suppose $c$ is in $(a,b)$, $$a<c<b$$
$$0<c<2$$
$$-2<c-2<0$$
$$-2<f(c)<0$$

Hence if $c \in (a,b)$, we must have $f(c) <0$ and hence $f(c) \neq \frac12$.

Intermediate value theorem requires continuity which is not satisfied in this function.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0^-} f(x) = 1\\
\lim_\limits{x\to 0^+} f(x) = -2\\
$

Choose the interval $[-1, 1]$
and we will break it into two subintervals
over the sub-interval $[-1,0)$ the range of $f(x)$ is $(1,2]$
over the sub-interval $[0,1)$ the range of $f(x)$ is $[-2,-1)$

over the entire interval, never does $f(x) = 0$

$0$ is a value between $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$, and there is no $x$ in $[-1,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$